# How to redirect urls with /#!/ with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect, litespeed

I need to redirect old website urls to new urls, but they all are indexed with **domain.com/#!/uri**, the **/#!/** is causing me problemes.
For example I need to redirect : /#!/themes to /thematique/.
I'd like to redirect to keep google SEO on the old pages.

I've tried multiple regex or even specify each url in my .htaccess, but all are ignored (because of the # I guess).

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/#!/themes$ /thematique/
```

OR

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)\%\23\%21\%2F(.*)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^ /%2? [R=301,L]
```

Am I doing this wrong or is this even possible ?

Thanks

Comment: You can not. Everything after the `#` is never sent to the server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I ended up making a js redirection to "clean" the url and after let my server redirections do the job.